# In the endomembrane system, after a protein leaves the rough ER, where does it go?

Tags: intracellular-transport

It can either go to the smooth ER then to the Golgi or it can go directly to the Golgi, right? Also, the smooth ER gets all of its material to synthesize things from the rough ER, right? Sorry, I looked around but couldn't really find a direct answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert at this but will do my best to answer your question based on the title. It depends on the protein! proteins can either be cytoplasmic, nuclear, transmembrane or secretory. Cytoplasmic proteins (as far as I know) get released to the cytoplasm after they have been folded correctly (through chaperones) and gone through the quality control mechanism. Nuclear proteins get transported through the nuclear pores, across the nuclear envelope through chaperones. Now for the transmembrane or secretory proteins, the fate of these proteins and where they go is decided by the ER (but obviously the information is there in the protein sequence). Transmembrane proteins have a signalling peptide and a transmembrane domain signal anchor sequence which ER recognises and through fancy looping and elongation across the ER membrane, the proteins is further translated by the ribosomes and eventually gets translocated to the cell membrane. There is very very nice nature review paper (Rapoport, 2007) about this and if you look at Figure 5, you will get a good ideas as to what goes on. For the secretory protein again its the interaction of the protein sequence with the ER membrane, helped with the ribosomes (in fact the groves in the ribosomes are key for making these fancy looping happen as the protein residues in ribosomes interact with peptide residues (amino acids) that are being produced on the fly), that processes it and sends it for secretion (Rapoport, 2007) and trans-golgi network is also important in the secretion process (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1424219/).

Hopefully these information would provide you with some hints.

Comment: there are also scads of poorly or uncharacterized lipid compartments within the cell.  I'm not sure we can even name them all, but the proteosome is an example, as are the vescicles that recycle receptors like insulin receptor within the cell.